# Limit the number of actions per second in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I go by limiting the number of actions a program in python takes per second. I know you can put time.sleep(n) between every line of code, but is there an easier way?

Comment: How are you defining "action"?

Comment: Why would you want to intentionally lower the speed?

Comment: To emphasize what @jwodder said, what is an action? You could call some function `f()` that itself runs 1000 lines of code. Is that function call 1 action?

Comment: @jwodder I'm defining an action as each line of the code performed.

Comment: (Puts on telepathy hat) probably the OP wants to do debugging, and throttling the code to clearly read whatever output its writing in console.

Comment: @user2464424 I don't need to debug the program, I need it to run slower for whoever is using it to understand what the program does more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this would be a great time for you to learn how to use a debugger. It will allow you to set breakpoints at certain points in your code, and see all sorts of values that are important to you at those points.

They can also let you run quick lines of code to see how those would interact with the current state of your program. Check out Python's debugger, [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

Answer (score 0):

On a lark I wrote this:

```
def slowdown(source,target,n,indent = 4):
    f = open(source)
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    f.close()
    f = open(target,'w')
    f.write('from time import sleep\n')
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line + '\n')
        if len(line.strip()) > 0:
            level = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
            if line.strip().endswith(':'):
                level += indent
            f.write(' '*level + 'sleep(' + str(n) + ')\n')
    f.close()
```

I then evaluated

```
slowdown('dice.py','slowdice.py',0.5)
```

where `dice.py` looks like:

```
#dice.py

import random

def roll(n):
    return random.randint(1,n)

grand_total = 0
for i in range(100):
    die = roll(6)
    count = 1 # I've already rolled once
    rolls = str(die)

    while die != 6:
        die = roll(6)
        rolls += str(die)
        count +=1

    print(rolls)
    grand_total += count

average = grand_total / 100
print('-'*20)
print("An average of %0.1f rolls required" % average)
```

It creates the following file (named `slowdice.py`):

```
from time import sleep
#dice.py
sleep(0.5)

import random
sleep(0.5)

def roll(n):
    sleep(0.5)
    return random.randint(1,n)
    sleep(0.5)

grand_total = 0
sleep(0.5)
for i in range(100):
    sleep(0.5)
    die = roll(6)
    sleep(0.5)
    count = 1 # I've already rolled once
    sleep(0.5)
    rolls = str(die)
    sleep(0.5)

    while die != 6:
        sleep(0.5)
        die = roll(6)
        sleep(0.5)
        rolls += str(die)
        sleep(0.5)
        count +=1
        sleep(0.5)

    print(rolls)
    sleep(0.5)
    grand_total += count
    sleep(0.5)

average = grand_total / 100
sleep(0.5)
print('-'*20)
sleep(0.5)
print("An average of %0.1f rolls required" % average)
sleep(0.5)
```

The resulting program is annoyingly slow to run.